# Overriding toString Using ES5 - Strange Behaviour

Tags: javascript, overriding, tostring, ecmascript-5

I would like to override toString using ES5. Given the following function which returns a complex number:

```
function complex(real, imaginary){
    var z = Object.create(complex.prototype);
    z.real = real;
    z.imaginary = imaginary;
    return z;
}
```

In order to override toString inherited from Object I do the following:

```
complex.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.real + " + " + this.imaginary + "*i";};
```

TEST:

```
var z = complex(1,1);
console.log(z);
```

RESULT:

```
{ real: 1, imaginary: 1 }
```

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on:

1. In many environments (including most browsers), `console.log` doesn't use `toString`, and
2. Your `complex` function doesn't return an object that uses `complex.prototype` as its prototype, so it doesn't have your `toString`. You're creating the object you return using `{}`, which creates an object directly inheriting from `Object.prototype`.

If you want to call `complex` without `new`, you need to explicitly use `complex.prototype` when creating your object, for instance via `Object.create(complex.prototype)`. (And then when logging, trigger `toString` on purpose, either calling it directly or converting to string in various other ways.)

Example:

```js
function complex(real, imaginary){
    var z = Object.create(complex.prototype);
    z.real = real;
    z.imaginary = imaginary;
    return z;
}
complex.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.real + " + " + this.imaginary + "*i";};

var z = complex(1, 1);
console.log(String(z));
```

You could call `complex` via `new` if you like (but I'm guessing you chose not to on purpose). Just FWIW:

```js
function Complex(real, imaginary){
    this.real = real;
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
}
Complex.prototype.toString = function(){ return this.real + " + " + this.imaginary + "*i";};

var z = new Complex(1, 1);
console.log(String(z));
```

or even

```js
class Complex {
    constructor(real, imaginary) {
        this.real = real;
        this.imaginary = imaginary;
    }
    toString() {
        return this.real + " + " + this.imaginary + "*i";
    }
}

const z = new Complex(1, 1);
console.log(String(z));
```

---

Side note: I've changed "imagenary" to "imaginary" above, which is the correct spelling in English. (Most of the text in your code seemed to be in English, but apologies if it's just that you translated the code in the question from another language and just forgot to translate "imagenary".)

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. Even after using complex.prototype logging a complex object would not triggers toString.

Comment: @AyoubFalah - Thanks! And yes, that's because of #1 above. You could also override `valueOf` because *some* consoles will use that, but mostly they don't call any method at all, they just show the raw contents of the object. But anything that uses the object as though it were a primitive (`+`, `-`, etc.) will trigger `toString` (or `valueOf` if you define that; which one is tried first varies according to the operation, but usually `valueOf` is tried first.).